# Rupee Symbol error

Tags: magento2, currency-symbol

[image]Indian currency symbol is not showing in magneto 2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, on the Admin sidebar, tap Stores and choose Configuration. In the panel on the left under General, choose Currency Setup and expand the Currency Options section

Please check with below url, which is provide the step how to configure currency 
 symbol.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-set-up-currency-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup currency and currency symbol as below

for currency setup :
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/currency-configuration.html

To setup currency symbol follow this.
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/currency-symbols.html

And if it still not display currency symbol then you need to install rupee font in your system.

Comment: if i copy currency symbol and paste into admin panel (currency symbol) it's automatically change into box

Comment: okay, you need to install font of "₹" symbol. Also check is there another site like flipkart, amazon displays "₹?

Comment: i check flipkart it's perfectly showing currency symbol

Comment: i need to install any other plugin for Indian currency symbol?

Comment: No no you don't need to install. paste "₹" symbol in price html  and check it displays or not? if not display then you need to install font

Comment: Where i paste this symbol?

Comment: i do not recommend but just for testing purpose add "<span class="price">₹110.00</span>" in list.phtml file and revert it after test. you can find that file under your theme Magento_catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to change the currency symbols, On the Admin sidebar,navigate to Stores>Currency Symbols,Just fill the box an Currency Symbol then save the configuration.
Again clear the cache,flush the cache and reindex the backend option system->cache managenment,system->Reindex management.Finally we got the result.

Comment: i already did it if i copy currency symbol and paste into admin panel it automatically change it into box symbol